# How to speed up Pandas rolling_sum()?

Tags: python, pandas

I have application that need to calculate the rolling sum of Pandas multilevel dataframe , and I want to find a way to shorten the processing time .

`mul_df()` is the function to create the demo multilevel dataframe.

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mul_df(level1_rownum, level2_rownum, col_num):
    ''' create multilevel dataframe '''

    index_name = ['IDX_1','IDX_2']
    col_name = ['COL'+str(x).zfill(3) for x in range(col_num)]

    first_level_dt = [['A'+str(x).zfill(4)]*level2_rownum for x in range(level1_rownum)]
    first_level_dt = list(itertools.chain(*first_level_dt))
    second_level_dt = ['B'+str(x).zfill(3) for x in range(level2_rownum)]*level1_rownum

    dt = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(level1_rownum*level2_rownum, col_num), columns=col_name)
    dt[index_name[0]] = first_level_dt
    dt[index_name[1]] = second_level_dt

    rst = dt.set_index(index_name, drop=True, inplace=False)
    return rst
```

For example :

```
>>> df = mul_df(4,5,3)
             COL000  COL001  COL002
IDX_1 IDX_2                        
A0000 B000   0.2317 -0.6122  0.2289
      B001  -0.9218 -0.2918  1.7295
      B002   0.1368  0.6659 -1.9193
      B003   0.3839 -0.8542 -0.3065
      B004   2.0361 -0.4601  1.1246
A0001 B000   0.3039 -0.6761  1.3762
      B001   1.1767  0.8465 -0.1745
      B002   0.4937  1.6774 -0.3038
      B003  -0.3627 -1.6413 -0.7373
      B004  -0.0149  1.5900  0.3385
A0002 B000   0.0326  0.2637  1.7990
      B001  -0.1071  0.6097 -0.2812
      B002  -0.2199  0.7360  1.9425
      B003  -1.0423  0.6763 -0.2479
      B004  -0.9024  0.3016 -2.7585
A0003 B000   0.2550  0.0470  0.6849
      B001   0.5986  0.3283  1.6327
      B002   0.8929 -1.1128 -0.9495
      B003  -0.5633  1.7935  0.1652
      B004   1.0417 -0.4833  0.3413
```

And use below command to calculate the rolling sum (window size is 4) for each column data groupby 'IDX_1':

```
>>> df.groupby(level='IDX_1').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x,4))
             COL000  COL001  COL002
IDX_1 IDX_2                        
A0000 B000      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B001      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B002      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B003  -0.1694 -1.0923 -0.2675
      B004   1.6350 -0.9402  0.6282
A0001 B000      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B001      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B002      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B003   1.6116  0.2064  0.1606
      B004   1.2928  2.4726 -0.8771
A0002 B000      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B001      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B002      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B003  -1.3367  2.2857  3.2125
      B004  -2.2717  2.3236 -1.3451
A0003 B000      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B001      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B002      NaN     NaN     NaN
      B003   1.1832  1.0559  1.5334
      B004   1.9699  0.5256  1.1898
>>>
```

And I try to calculate the `rolling_sum()` for a big dataframe.

```
In [1]: df = mul_df(1000,25,1000)
In [2]: timeit df.groupby(level='IDX_1').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x,4))
1 loops, best of 3: 52.1 s per loop
```

It costs 52.1s for a (1000*25, 1000) dataframe. How to speed up the rolling_sum (I mean is there other way to achieve the same calculation result but costs less time ) ?

**EDIT( Add memory error msg for waitingkuo's solution)**

```
In [1]: df = mul_df(1000,25,1000)

In [2]: k2 = df.frs(4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1b54b2662162> in <module>()
----> 1 k2 = df.frs(4)

F:\STK Analysis\Kits\Dev_Tools\FinReporter\FM_CORE.pyc in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    149         from datetime import datetime
    150         t1 = datetime.now()
--> 151         rst = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    152         t2 = datetime.now()
    153         print "Time: %0.3f"%((t2-t1).seconds + (t2-t1).microseconds/1000000.0)

F:\STK Analysis\Kits\Dev_Tools\FinReporter\FM_CORE.pyc in _frs(df, n)
    864     ''' fast_rolling_sum , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652343/how-to-speed-up-pandas-rolling-sum '''
    865     grp = df.groupby(level='STK_ID')
--> 866     return np.sum([grp.shift(i) for i in range(n)])
    867 DataFrame.frs = _frs
    868

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    259                 return self.apply(curried_with_axis)
    260             except Exception:
--> 261                 return self.apply(curried)
    262
    263         return wrapper

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    320         func = _intercept_function(func)
    321         f = lambda g: func(g, *args, **kwargs)
--> 322         return self._python_apply_general(f)
    323
    324     def _python_apply_general(self, f):

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    323
    324     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 325         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self.obj, self.axis)
    326
    327         return self._wrap_applied_output(keys, values,

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in apply(self, f, data, axis, keep_internal)
    583         if hasattr(splitter, 'fast_apply') and axis == 0:
    584             try:
--> 585                 values, mutated = splitter.fast_apply(f, group_keys)
    586                 return group_keys, values, mutated
    587             except lib.InvalidApply:

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in fast_apply(self, f, names)
   2136             return [], True
   2137
-> 2138         sdata = self._get_sorted_data()
   2139         results, mutated = lib.apply_frame_axis0(sdata, f, names, starts, ends)
   2140

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in _get_sorted_data(self)
   2103
   2104     def _get_sorted_data(self):
-> 2105         return self.data.take(self.sort_idx, axis=self.axis)
   2106
   2107     def _chop(self, sdata, slice_obj):

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in take(self, indices, axis)
   2900             new_values = com.take_2d(self.values,
   2901                                      com._ensure_int64(indices),
-> 2902                                      axis=axis)
   2903             if axis == 0:
   2904                 new_columns = self.columns

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in take_2d(arr, indexer, out, mask, needs_masking, axis, fill_value)
    426     elif dtype_str in ('float64', 'object', 'datetime64[ns]'):
    427         if out is None:
--> 428             out = np.empty(out_shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    429         take_f = _get_take2d_function(dtype_str, axis=axis)
    430         take_f(arr, _ensure_int64(indexer), out=out, fill_value=fill_value)

MemoryError:

In [3]:
```

Comment: this is currently a known issue, see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3185, probably will be addressed for 0.12

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to the update !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about shift it first and then add them together?

```
In [223]: def my_rolling_sum(d, n):
   .....:     g = d.groupby(level='IDX_1')
   .....:     return np.sum([g.shift(i) for i in range(n)])
   .....:
```

Let's see the performance:

```
In [224]: df = mul_df(1000,25,1000)

In [225]: timeit df.groupby(level='IDX_1').apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x,4))
1 loops, best of 3: 32.4 s per loop

In [230]: timeit my_rolling_sum(df, 4)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.15 s per loop
```

### Edit

While it costs too much memory, I try to give it some modifications:

```
In [5]: def my_rolling_sum(d, n):
   ...:     g = d.groupby(level='IDX_1')
   ...:     result = g.shift(0)
   ...:     for i in range(1, n):
   ...:         result = result + g.shift(i)
   ...:
```

Hope it might help you.

Comment: great code, thanks. on my machine, it offers 3x speed up. But it seems to cost more memory , running for a mul_df(1000,25,1000) will cause memory error on my machine (3G RAM), I attach the error msg .

Comment: Yes, it improves. Thanks again, it really helps a lot  .